# How can I remove email and other extra fields from User table in ASP.NET boilerplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate, user-management

I have a ASP.NET boilerplate project, and the user's login/register has to be based on OTP code. So there are several redundant fields in User table, including Email and IsEmailConfirmed.

I tried not inheriting my User from abpUser, then got error in my UserManager which inherits from AbpUserManager. Seems like everything is tied to AbpUser and AbpUserBase.

I know I can override AbpUserManager methods, and maybe put some default values for these fields. But is there a clean way to get rid of these fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fluent API in your DbContext's `OnModelCreating` method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<CustomUser>().Ignore(x => x.Email);
    builder.Entity<CustomUser>().Ignore(x => x.EmailConfirmed);
}
```

This will result in those fields not getting mapped. However they still will be the part of your `CustomUser` class, because they are inherited from the `IdentityUser`. Note that this can break some methods of the `UserManager` (e.g. `FindByEmailAsync`).

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Your solution does exactly what was in my mind. However, I decided not to do that. Because it's so tricky and can make bugs that I'm not aware of.